# How can I only apply my check if the jQuery UI slider has moved?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, filter, show-hide, jquery-ui-slider

I'm trying to build a set of filters with jQuery UI sliders so a user can slide them and filter out items based on data-attributes applied to the objects (in this case it's time).

See fiddle for code and test case: http://jsfiddle.net/thecrumb/7Err4/1/

```
function doShowHideBadges() {
    //show all initially then loop through each
    $('div[id^="block"]').removeClass('hidden').each(function (e) {
        var sliderValue1 = $('.slider-range0').slider("option", "values");
        var sliderValue2 = $('.slider-range1').slider("option", "values");
        console.clear();
        console.log(sliderValue1[0] + '-' + sliderValue1[1] + ' | ' + sliderValue2[0] + '-' + sliderValue2[1]);
        if (
            ($(this).data('departuretime0') < sliderValue1[0] || $(this).data('departuretime0') > sliderValue1[1]) &&
            ($(this).data('arrivaltime0') < sliderValue2[0] || $(this).data('arrivaltime0') > sliderValue2[1])
        ) {
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });
}
```

I finally have this working like I want *BUT* only if the user moves both sliders.  What I need is the objects to be shown/hidden based on either filter - not both.

Comment: I checked your fiddle. The doShowHideBadges() is executing whenever a slider handle slides.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you fighting against their `api`?

Use the `slide` event from [jQuery UI:](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide)

```
$( ".slider-range0" ).slider({
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        // show and hide functions in here

    }
});

...
```

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle?  I am using the slide event - I call doShowHideBadges() from there.